# Ethereum Wallet - Access via 24 words recovery phrase fails

Tags: metamask, etherscan, recovery, passphrase

I have x ETH in a Ledger Nano S wallet. The hardware dongle broke. I have the 24 words recovery phrase. Last time I had a look at the wallet via the recovery phrase was on 6. August 2021. (I did an inventory back then.)
Today I wanted to access the wallet. I converted the 24 words recovery phrase to a m/44'/60'/0'/0/0 private key and imported the wallet with this key into MetaMask. It shows me an empty wallet (0 ETH).
Next I tried to load the wallet into the iOs app Trust Wallet by typing in the 24 words directly. It also shopws me an empty wallet (0 ETH).
Then I opened the wallet with the 24 words recovery phrase directly in myetherwallet.com (ignoring that this isn't recommended to do). It also shows me an empty wallet (0 ETH).

Now I could understand that my wallet is simply empty and if that's the case and someone stole it, it would be a pity but well I guess that's live.

However, I happen to have the transaction where I transferred the x ETH into the wallet. I'm not an expert by far, but based on what I can understand from the results showing on https://etherscan.io/address it should show not only an ingoing transaction into my wallet, but also an outgoing transaction if someone withdrew the coins, right?

With my transaction I see only the x ETH going in, but never going out.

I know that the 24 words recovery phrase written on paper is correct, because I used it to withdrew bitcoins last year in August. (And as mentioned inventorized my balance in the Eth wallet.)

What I noticed: the computed public key (starting with 0x) calculated by https://iancoleman.io/bip39/#english based on the 24 words pass phrase differs from the address shown as destination of my transaction on etherscan.io

What am I doing wrong? Did something change since last year? Is my old pass phrase now computing a different public/private key pair than it used to do in the past? (i.e., did the algorithm change)

Comment: In this article https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005200009-Set-up-and-use-MyEtherWallet?docs=true, they mention the path `m/44'/60'/0'/0`.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to
https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/4415198323089-How-Ledger-device-generates-24-word-recovery-phrase?docs=true

It seems that seed phrase generation is using the BIP 39 standard for generation. I suspect that Metamask/trustwallet might be adhering to different standards and thus resulting in you being unable to import although your seed phrase should be correct.

Looking at what wallets support BIP 39 standard referring to
https://coinguides.org/bip39-wallets/

[image]
[image]

You should be able to import your wallet from one of the options above.

If you have your checked your address on etherscan before, you can see if there have been any outgoing transactions / current balance.

Hope it helps!